# Xamarin - Grouping List Views

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin

I've got some issues with grouping my List Views.
When I `isgroupingenabled = "true"` my List only shows the `groupDisplayBinding` name.

I've read and tried so many things and wasn't able to apply them to my project I need your help now.

I've seen I need to put an `Observablecollection` but don't know where and how to do it.

**My Model**

```
        public class League
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string logo { get; set; }
        public string flag { get; set; }
    }

    public class HomeTeam
    {
        public int team_id { get; set; }
        public string team_name { get; set; }
        public string logo { get; set; }
    }

    public class AwayTeam
    {
        public int team_id { get; set; }
        public string team_name { get; set; }
        public string logo { get; set; }
    }

    public class Score
    {
        public string halftime { get; set; }
        public string fulltime { get; set; }
        public string extratime { get; set; }
        public string penalty { get; set; }
    }

    public class Fixture
    {
        public int fixture_id { get; set; }
        public int league_id { get; set; }
        public League league { get; set; }
        public DateTime event_date { get; set; }
        public int event_timestamp { get; set; }
        public int? firstHalfStart { get; set; }
        public int? secondHalfStart { get; set; }
        public string round { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string statusShort { get; set; }
        public int elapsed { get; set; }
        public string venue { get; set; }
        public string referee { get; set; }
        public HomeTeam homeTeam { get; set; }
        public AwayTeam awayTeam { get; set; }
        public int? goalsHomeTeam { get; set; }
        public int? goalsAwayTeam { get; set; }
        public Score score { get; set; }
    }

    public class Api
    {
        public int results { get; set; }
        public List<Fixture> Fixtures { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootFixtures
    {
        public Api api { get; set; }
    }
```

**My JSON :** (Part of it)

```
{"api": {
"results": 162,
"fixtures": [
  {
    "fixture_id": 234670,
    "league_id": 900,
    "league": {
      "name": "Division 1",
      "country": "Saudi-Arabia",
      "logo": null,
      "flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/sa.svg"
    },
    "event_date": "2020-03-10T00:00:00+00:00",
    "event_timestamp": 1583798400,
    "firstHalfStart": null,
    "secondHalfStart": null,
    "round": "Regular Season - 28",
    "status": "Match Postponed",
    "statusShort": "PST",
    "elapsed": 0,
    "venue": "Prince Saud bin Jalawi Stadium (al-Khobar (Khobar))",
    "referee": null,
    "homeTeam": {
      "team_id": 2933,
      "team_name": "Al-Qadisiyah FC",
      "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/teams/2933.png"
    },
    "awayTeam": {
      "team_id": 2928,
      "team_name": "Al Khaleej Saihat",
      "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/teams/2928.png"
    },
    "goalsHomeTeam": null,
    "goalsAwayTeam": null,
    "score": {
      "halftime": null,
      "fulltime": null,
      "extratime": null,
      "penalty": null
    }
  }
]
```

}
}

**ListMatchPage :**

```
    public partial class ListMatchs : ContentPage
{
    string JsonLeagues = "The Json Below"
    public ListMatchs()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var Leagues = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootFixtures>(JsonLeagues);

        LeaguesList.ItemsSource = Leagues.api.Fixtures;

    }
}
```

I'm new at dev and here I Hope my english wasn't too bad.
**edit : 
MyXAML :**

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Futurs matchs" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
        <ListView x:Name="LeaguesList" GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Path=League.name}"
                  GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding Path=League.name}"
                  IsGroupingEnabled="True" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell Height="30">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Grid.Column="0" Aspect="AspectFit" Source="{Binding Path=homeTeam.logo}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" FontSize="15" FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=homeTeam.team_name}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" FontSize="15" FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=awayTeam.team_name}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                            <Image Grid.Column="3" Aspect="AspectFit" Source="{Binding Path=awayTeam.logo}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: where is LeaguesList defined?

Comment: Post you xaml also then I'll tell you how to group data properly.

Comment: Oops I forgot it LeaguesList is my ListviewName defined in the XAML.
I edited my question with it

Answer (score 0):

The model you added to the ItemsSource should in a right format as the [document mentioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#grouping), I wrote a example for you and you can check the code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    ObservableCollection<myModel> FixtureCollection = new ObservableCollection<myModel>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        League LeagueOne = new League() { name = "one" };
        League LeagueTwo = new League() { name = "two" };
        League LeagueThree = new League() { name = "three" };

        HomeTeam HomeTeamOne = new HomeTeam() { team_name = "HomeTeamOne" };
        HomeTeam HomeTeamTwo = new HomeTeam() { team_name = "HomeTeamTwo" };
        HomeTeam HomeTeamThree = new HomeTeam() { team_name = "HomeTeamThree" };

        AwayTeam AwayTeamOne = new AwayTeam() { team_name = "AwayTeamOne" };
        AwayTeam AwayTeamTwo = new AwayTeam() { team_name = "AwayTeamTwo" };
        AwayTeam AwayTeamThree = new AwayTeam() { team_name = "AwayTeamThree" };


        Fixture FixtureOne = new Fixture() { league = LeagueOne, homeTeam = HomeTeamOne, awayTeam = AwayTeamOne};
        Fixture FixtureTwo = new Fixture() { league = LeagueTwo, homeTeam = HomeTeamTwo, awayTeam = AwayTeamTwo };
        Fixture FixtureThree = new Fixture() { league = LeagueThree, homeTeam = HomeTeamThree, awayTeam = AwayTeamThree };


        myModel myModelOne = new myModel(FixtureOne.league.name) { FixtureOne };
        myModel myModelTwo = new myModel(FixtureTwo.league.name) { FixtureTwo };
        myModel myModelThree = new myModel(FixtureThree.league.name) {FixtureThree };

        FixtureCollection.Add(myModelOne);
        FixtureCollection.Add(myModelTwo);
        FixtureCollection.Add(myModelThree);

        LeaguesList.ItemsSource = FixtureCollection;

        BindingContext = this;
    }
}

public class myModel : List<Fixture>
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public myModel( string Name) {
        name = Name;
    }
}
```

And in code behind:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="Futurs matchs" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
    <ListView x:Name="LeaguesList" 
              GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding name}"
              GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding name}"
              IsGroupingEnabled="True" HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell Height="30">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.Column="0" Aspect="AspectFit" Source="{Binding Path=homeTeam.logo}" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" FontSize="15" FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=homeTeam.team_name}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="2" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" FontSize="15" FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=awayTeam.team_name}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                        <Image Grid.Column="3" Aspect="AspectFit" Source="{Binding Path=awayTeam.logo}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

I also uploaded my sample project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/group-listView) and feel free to ask me any question.

**Update:**

I think what you really need is `OrderBy` not `GroupBy`:

```
LeaguesList.ItemsSource = FixturesCollection.OrderBy(f => f.FixtureLeague).ToList();
```

When you use `GroupBy`, you can set a breakpoint right there to check the `LeaguesList.ItemsSource`, you will find the structure has been change, the count of `LeaguesList.ItemsSource` becomes 56.

There is another problem in your `xaml`, the `GroupDisplayBinding` should bind to `FixtureLeague` not name:

```
<ListView x:Name="LeaguesList" GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding FixtureLeague}"
```

Comment: First of all Thank you for your answer.   The fact is that in the Json I have thousands of fixtures and can't add them one by one cause they change everyday by calling an web api.

Comment: You can use a for statement to add, what I did is just an example.

Comment: I now have my games and their owns leagues but they are not grouped by leagues
I Think a groupby in the Collection should be good no?
For now thank you @JackHua

Comment: What do you mean by a groupby in the Collection? Show me the code and then I can help you better.

Comment: I posted an answer to show my actual setting.
When it will be over i'll edit it with the right answer Without forgetting to mention you

Comment: Maybe the collection can't group by FixtureLeague?

Comment: I can see by selecting items that it is grouped but my bindings seems not working.

Comment: Can you share me a Minimal, Reproducible Example?

Comment: I zipped it on my drive :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A_bTRlXJC81gv6RWwqaV4RPCtVDZ67R8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Divox974 Please check my updated answer, don't forget to mark the answer if it solves your problem:).

Answer (score 0):

@JackHUA here is what I did :

```
XAML.CS :



    ObservableCollection<groupedfix> FixturesCollection = new ObservableCollection<groupedfix>();
public ListMatchs()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            var Leagues = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootFixtures>(JsonLeagues);
            foreach (var match in Leagues.api.Fixtures)

            {
                int fixtureid = match.fixture_id;
                DateTime fixturedate = match.event_date;

                int FixtureLeagueid = match.league_id;
                string FixtureLeague = match.league.name;
                string FixtureLeaguelogo = match.league.logo;

                string Hometeamname = match.homeTeam.team_name;
                string Hometeamlogo = match.homeTeam.logo;
                string Awayteamname = match.awayTeam.team_name;
                string Awayteamlogo = match.awayTeam.logo;

                HomeTeam HOMETEAM = new HomeTeam() { team_name = Hometeamname, logo = Hometeamlogo };
                AwayTeam AWAYTEAM = new AwayTeam() { team_name = Awayteamname, logo = Awayteamlogo };
                League LEAGUE = new League() { logo = FixtureLeaguelogo, name = FixtureLeague };

                Fixture MATCH = new Fixture() { fixture_id = fixtureid, event_date = fixturedate, league_id = FixtureLeagueid, league = LEAGUE, homeTeam = HOMETEAM, awayTeam = AWAYTEAM };

                groupedfix GROUPEDFIX = new groupedfix(FixtureLeague) { MATCH };

                FixturesCollection.Add(GROUPEDFIX);

            }

            LeaguesList.ItemsSource = FixturesCollection;

        }


        public class groupedfix : List<Fixture>
        {
            public string FixtureLeague { get; set; }

            public groupedfix(string Name )
            {
                FixtureLeague = Name;

            }

        }
```

**XAML :**

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Futurs matchs" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
        <ListView x:Name="LeaguesList" GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding FixtureLeague}"
                  IsGroupingEnabled="True" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemTapped="Newgameclick">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate> 
                    <ViewCell Height="30">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Grid.Column="0" Aspect="AspectFit" Source="{Binding Path=homeTeam.logo}"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" FontSize="15" FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=homeTeam.team_name}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" FontSize="15" FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=awayTeam.team_name}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                            <Image Grid.Column="3" Aspect="AspectFit" Source="{Binding Path=awayTeam.logo}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

The image result :
[See the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwSX5.png)

But when I change

```
LeaguesList.ItemsSource = FixturesCollection;
```

in

```
LeaguesList.ItemsSource = FixturesCollection.GroupBy(F => F.FixtureLeague);
```

I get this : [See the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrdh1.png)

With error :

```
[0:] Binding:'FixtureLeague' property not found on 'System.Linq.Grouping`2[System.String,BeastTIPS.Pages.ListMatchs+groupedfix]'...
        [0:] Binding: 'homeTeam' property not found on 'BeastTIPS.Pages.ListMatchs+groupedfix'...
    [0:] Binding: 'awayTeam' property not found on 'BeastTIPS.Pages.ListMatchs+groupedfix'...
```

The List is groupedby but my Binding are not found 
I can't find what property to Bind.